# how to traverse through xml node and to update the values in the node in karate framework

Tags: xml, karate

how traverse through xml node and to update the values in the node  in karate framework

I am reading the seperate xml file and loading into the feature file
Scenario:
* def payload = read('classpath:TL/Payload/Sample.xml')
* print payload
* print payload/Message/Transfer
* string jsonPayload = payload/Message/
* print jsonPayload

Fails with error

<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "Message" is not defined

- .:program(Unnamed:1)

Reading the Sample.xml as the external file
able the print the payload

Expected to update few nodes value with random values
so try to traversing the node

Comment: read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - please edit your question with a simple example